# Stiefel Whitney Class Tautological Line Bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\gamma$ be the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^1$. Is it possible to compute the second Stiefel Whitney Class $w_2(\gamma)$ from the axioms, and if so, can you give a hint how?

Comment: You do not want to use the fact that the stiefel whitney classes are the mod 2 reductions of the chern classes?

Comment: @ThomasRot We haven't covered those yet (and we will), so I would rather do it without

Comment: One idea: There is a homotopically non-trivial map $RP^2\rightarrow S^2$, by mapping everything in the one skeleton to the southpole. Maybe one can understand what happens to the tautological bundle under this map. If this pullback has a non-zero $w_2$, one knows that the original bundle has a non-zero $w_2$.